# Confusion with Johansen Test and interpretation in Vector Error Correction Model

Tags: econometrics, cointegration, granger-causality, vector-error-correction-model

I am in the process of estimating a Vector Error Correction Model for a set of ten variables. I have confirmed that all the series are I(1), however I have become confused by the results of my Johansen test/VEC specification.

My Johansen test has found that four cointegrating relations exist, which I have used in my VECM. However, my confusion lies with the interpretation of the results. Primarily, I was hoping to test whether 9 variables (Xi) have a significant impact on one other variable (Y).

From my understanding, traditional interpretation is therefore not possible, as the cointegrating vectors cannot be uniquely identified, and all we know is that a long-run relationship exists between the variables, with the eigenvectors being said to span the cointegrating space. Equally, given that lagged values of the variables are included in the VECM, the best way to to therefore determine the impact of a change in Xi on Y would be to use impulse response functions. From a predictive standpoint, however, only variables that are found to Granger cause Y.

Am I right in my interpretation of my results? E.g. is this, in general, the most we can say about the relationship, given the number of cointegrating relationships? Ideally, I was hoping to normalise the cointegrating relation with respect to Y so that I could determine whether each X variable has a positive/negative impact on Y over the long run (by reversing the coefficients generated by the Johansen test) and note whether the coefficients for the lags of each variable are significant (and therefore interpret this as SR significance), but, as I say, it is my understanding that this kind of interpretation is inaccessible when multiple cointegrating vectors exist, with caution when interpreting the results being paramount given the simultaneous nature of the VECM.

Would anyone be able to confirm/deny the above? This forms part of my thesis and is consequently the first VECM I have estimated.

I can of course provide more details should they be necessary. Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Thank you in advance!